AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'add'
I am trying to use database session in the middleware (to write metrics to the database)
I am using  fastapi.params.Depends in @app.middleware("http")
I read this question FastAPI - dependency inside Middleware? and was using solution from this question
My code:
database.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://username@localhost/feast_db" # Checked that psql postgresql://username@localhost/feast_db is working

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

Main app:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Request, Response, status
from fastapi.params import Depends

from myapp.metrics_service import models, schemas
from myapp.metrics_service.database import SessionLocal, engine


models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine) # create database table


def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

def get_app(store: "feast.FeatureStore"):
    proto_json.patch()

    app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(get_db)])
    request_id_contextvar = contextvars.ContextVar("request_id", default=None)
    ...
    @app.middleware("http")
    async def log_requests(request: Request, call_next, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
        response = await call_next(request)
        ...
        curr_metric = models.Metric(rqid=request_id, name="request_duration", duration_ms=total_time_ms)
        print("XXX_ curr_metric")
        db.session.add(curr_metric)
        db.session.commit()
        return response
    



I have an error
db.add(curr_metric)
AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'add'

How to fix the error?

app = FastAPI() only

@sahasrara62 could you please elaborate?

app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(get_db)])  --> app = FastAPI()

Depends doesn't work for middlewares. It works only for endpoints (FastAPI solves dependencies before the endpoint function execution).

To extend on what @YuriiMotov says; only the controller endpoints resolve dependencies, so what you have in your middleware is the actual dependency object. Drop the dependency from the signature and just call get_db() directly - it's just a plain function.

I checked https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/ru/reference/dependencies/ and question that you linked, and noticed that they are using Depends() which imported like
from fastapi import Depends

without ".params" subdirectory.
And in both cases they are don't use Depends().add() or Depends().commit(). They are just declared dependency in function declaration and that is it.

I replaced from fastapi.params import Depends with from fastapi import Depends but still see the same error

If you didn’t removed the following strings:
db.session.add(curr_metrics)
db.session.commit()
Error will not leave you.

Looks like you trying to add metrics to your db, using Depends(), but Depends() is only declares dependency, it means that you can’t use any functionality of objects that you set in Depends().
Example:
l = []
o = Depends(l)
you can’t use
o.append()

The issue isn't about declaring - it would get resolved properly in a controller function signature. The thing is that FastAPI only resolve dependencies from a controller signature, and not when used in a middleware (and it would get resolved to the return value, so you could call append/etc. on the resulting value from the dependency). But since the dependencies are just functions, you can call the function directly instead of using Depends in this case.
